# jQuery isotope not working with my layout

Tags: jquery, html, layout, jquery-isotope

I am having some trouble with the jquery isotope plugin, for some reason it will not work with my current layout, basically I want a sidebar on the left, and on the right a container containing bunch of little boxes (isotope elements) that re-orient according to the browsers size, as isotope does.

For some reason isotope does not like my layout, on load the site briefly shows the isotope elements on the right, but they then quickly disappear, leaving the `#container` without a width.

This is the first time I am using the plugin, and I am not sure if I am maybe missing something very basic, but when I remove all other html and only leave `#container`, isotope functions as expected.

I have set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ftg8u/) with all of my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think isotope works very well with floats. Instead you can use margin to move the isotope container over to the right and then absolutely position the left.

I updated your example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ftg8u/7/ 
does this work for you?

Comment: Yeap, that worked perfectly, thanks! I actually got it working myself, using that exact same fix, using margins and absolute positioning instead of floats, the same way they use it on the isotope website. :) Thanks again!